# mysql left join with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm building a database for my work and I'm having trouble figuring out how to build this query.

The tables relevant to my problem are:

job

Surgical_Planning - has job as foreign key, exists for some jobs, doesn't for others

Medical_Model - has job as foreign key, 1 to 1 relationship with job

This is a working query where I don't have any information about the surgical planning

```
    SELECT
    job,
    physician_idphysician as Physician,
    patient_idpatient as Patient,
    status,
    DATE_FORMAT(scan_date, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Scan_Date,
    DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Recieved,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_required, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Date_Required
    FROM
    job, patient_has_physician as phys, Scan, Medical_Model as med
    WHERE
    Scan.job_job = job AND phys.job_job = job
    AND med.job_job = job AND job.type =  'medical
```

I think I want to do a Left join so that it will display every job in order, with all the information in the query above, but then when there is a Surgical_Planning for a job # I want there to be a column for that as well. Here is my attempt that is not working

```
    SELECT
    job,
    physician_idphysician as Physician,
    patient_idpatient as Patient,
    status,
    DATE_FORMAT(scan_date, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Scan_Date,
    DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Recieved,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_required, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i%p') as Date_Required
    FROM
    job, patient_has_physician as phys, Scan, Medical_Model as med

    LEFT JOIN Surgical_Planning ON job.job = Surgical_Planning.job_job
    AND Scan.job_job = job AND phys.job_job = job
    AND med.job_job = job AND job.type = 'medical'
```

I can get this basic left join working the way I want, but if I want to add more columns like above it doesn't work.

```
    SELECT job, planning_id
    FROM job
    LEFT JOIN Surgical_Planning ON job = Surgical_Planning.job_job
```

could a subquery be used as well? I can figure out these more basic queries but really have trouble with these more complex join and subquery ones. any advice is appreciated.

EDIT --- Job table schema

---

-- Table `mmrl`.`job`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mmrl`.`job` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mmrl`.`job` (

`job` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`status` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,

PRIMARY KEY (`job`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change

```
LEFT JOIN Surgical_Planning ON job.job = Surgical_Planning.job_job
AND Scan.job_job = job AND phys.job_job = job
AND med.job_job = job AND job.type = 'medical'
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN Surgical_Planning ON job.job = Surgical_Planning.job_job
WHERE Scan.job_job = job AND phys.job_job = job
AND med.job_job = job AND job.type = 'medical'
```

EDIT:

the left join occurs against the table to the left of the actual `LEFT JOIN` syntax.  Move job to the end of your from list and try again.

```
FROM patient_has_physician as phys, Scan, Medical_Model as med, job
```